# What is the angular velocity of a wheel as a function of time as it is spun up by a DC motor?

Tags: energy, electricity, everyday-life, power, angular-velocity

For the sake of concreteness, let us consider a brushed DC motor. I am trying to predict how much a wheel spins up when it is connected to a DC motor for a certain amount of time $t$. Let's say I power the motor at a voltage $V$ and current $I$ for a time $t$. Then presumably there would be a constant power $P$ supplied for a time $t$.

The kinetic energy of the wheel at $t$ would be $\frac{1}{2}I\omega(t)^{2}$ where $I$ is the rotational inertia and $\omega(t)$ is the angular velocity. I expect
$$ Pt = \frac{1}{2}I\omega(t)^{2}, $$
which yields
$$ \omega(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2Pt}{I}}. $$

This seems to imply that the angular velocity increases proportionally to the square root of time. I'm not completely sure this is correct. I imagine that as $\omega(t)$ increases, friction forces play a larger role which lead to a saturation in angular velocity, [as pointed out in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285452). Is the above formula an accurate prediction? If not,  what would be an accurate way to model the angular velocity?

Comment: Initially, there is a part of constant torque and then a part of linearly decreasing torque. Some high end designs have a constant power region, but typical DC motors generally do not.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily set both the voltage and the current at the same time. Voltage across the terminals of an ideal DC motor is strictly proportional to the shaft speed, and current is strictly proportional to the torque. If starting from rest, when you connect the motor to the power supply, the motor _must_ pull the supply voltage down to zero. (For a practical motor, voltage will not be pulled _all_ the way down to zero because of the motor winding's inherent serial resistance.)

Comment: A more realistic question would assume a power supply that is both voltage limited and current limited. Starting from rest, the power supply would provide constant current, I, resulting in some constant torque, $\tau{}$. As the wheel accelerates, the voltage would rise until it hits the limit, V, at which point, the current would fall to zero\*, and the speed would become constant. [\* zero current in the ideal, but a practical motor would draw some current because it would have to supply enough torque to keep the wheel spinning at a constant rate in spite of friction.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a generic motor torque curve that looks like this

[image: fig1]

There are three distinct regions to this curve, that you might encounter with DC motors. We will attempt to devise equations for speed versus time, for each type of curve. More precisely, I will calculate the time it takes to reach a certain speed.

The geneal equation of motion is $$T=I\dot{\omega}$$ where $\dot{\omega}$ is the rotational acceleration, $I$ is the total mass moment of inertia and $T$ is torque (all in consistent units).

The general formulata for time, when acceleration is a function of speed only, is $$ t = t_0 + \int_{\omega_0}^\omega \frac{1}{\dot{\omega}}\;{\rm d}\omega = t_0 + \int_{\omega_0}^\omega \frac{I}{T}\;{\rm d}\omega$$ where $\omega_0$ and $t_0$ are the initial speed and time for which this equation is applied

1. **Constant Torque** - The segment *AB* is characterized by $\boxed{T = T_A}$. Starting from zero speed and time, the time $t$ to reach $\omega < \omega_B$ is $$ t= \int_0^\omega \tfrac{I}{T_A}\,{\rm d}\omega = \frac{I\,\omega}{T_A} $$ at the limit when $\omega = \omega_B$ the time would be $t_B = \frac{I \omega_B}{T_A}$
2. **Constant Power** - The segment *BC* is characterized by $\boxed{T = \frac{ T_B \omega_B }{\omega}} $. Starting from $\omega_B$ and $t_B$ as calculated above, elasped time is $$ t=t_B + \int_{\omega_B}^\omega \frac{I}{ \frac{T_B \omega_B}{\omega} }\,{\rm d}\omega = \frac{I \omega_B}{T_A} + \frac{I (\omega^2 - \omega_B^2)}{2 T_B \omega_B} $$ <sub>Note that $T_B=T_A$ here.</sub>

   The time and the end of this segment is $t_C = \frac{I ( \omega_B^2+\omega_C^2)}{2 T_A \omega_B}$
3. **Linear Torque** - The segment *CD* is characterized by $ \boxed{T = T_C \left(1 - \frac{\omega-\omega_C}{\omega_D-\omega_C}\right)}$. Starting from $\omega_C$ and $t_C$ as calculated above the elapsed time is $$ t=t_C + \int_{\omega_C}^\omega \frac{I}{ T_C \left(1 - \frac{\omega-\omega_C}{\omega_D-\omega_C}\right) }\,{\rm d}\omega = \frac{I ( \omega_B^2+\omega_C^2)}{2 T_A \omega_B} + \frac{I (\omega_C - \omega_D)}{T_C} \ln \left( \frac{\omega-\omega_C}{\omega_D - \omega_C} \right) $$ <sub>Note that due to constant power $T_C = T_B \frac{\omega_B}{\omega_C}$</sub>.

   The time to reach $\omega_D$ is infinite due to the fact that $
   \ln \left( \frac{\omega-\omega_C}{\omega_D - \omega_C} \right) |_{\omega \rightarrow \omega_D} = \infty$

Comment: This is very interesting. I can follow your reasoning, but do you know where you got the three regimes from? Is it well-known in electrical engineering or is it an educated guess/approximation?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal - google DC motor torque curve and you will see what is typical.